# Issue rotating points in the geometry node to center

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a bunch of "Crosses" that I am attempting to point to the center of the object that holds the geometry node (so (0,0)) which is just a smile equation of (Tan(y/x)) but for some reason I can't get the points to rotate, making me think that I have done the attribute node wrong.

this is the simple attribute node group that is (supposed to be) doing the math:
[image]

but for some reason, the points don't seem to change rotation.
[image]

Comment: i am not sure whether i got you right....so if my answer doesn't help...you should definitely improve your question, so that is is clear, what you want (a pic with what you want to have would help a lot)

Comment: The result of tangent is not going to produce an angle.  Instead use arctangent in python would use `atan2(y, x)` which allows for x = 0.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749246/python-atan-or-atan2-what-should-i-use  _ie_ what angle produces that tangent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object (in my case a cube) and you have point instances (in my case a cone) you can align them with this node group:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: ...I don't even want to know how many *Geometry Nodes* corpses are lying around here on BSE, just because all the people don't want to bother to mark an answer as solved. Always take, never give. It's really tedious sometimes. Thanks Chris, that you still stay so eager and unwaveringly bring such great answers! ...so despite outdated question/answer: +1 ;-)

Comment: I might be the one on BLENDER SE with the most not accepted answers….

Comment: That could actually be the case. In any case, you have my respect!